# Creating a visualization with 2 Y-Axis scales

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently trying to plot the price of the 1080 graphics card against the price of bitcoin over time, but the scales of the Y axis are just way off. This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np

GPUDATA = pd.read_csv("1080Prices.csv") 
BCDATA = pd.read_csv("BitcoinPrice.csv")

date = pd.to_datetime(GPUDATA["Date"])
price = GPUDATA["Price_USD"]

date1 = pd.to_datetime(BCDATA["Date"])
price1 = BCDATA["Close"]

plot(date, price)
plot(date1, price1)
```

And that produces this:

[image]

The GPU prices, of course, are in blue and the price of bitcoin is in orange. I am fairly new to visualizations and I'm having a rough time finding anything online that could help me fix this issue. Some of the suggestions I found on here seem to deal with plotting data from a single datasource, but my data comes from 2 datasources.

One has entries of the GPU price in a given day, the other has the open, close, high, and low price of bitcoin in a given day. I am struggling to find a solution, any advice would be more than welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is *twin* the X-axis, such that both plots will share the X-axis, but have separate Y-axes. That can be done in this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

GPUDATA = pd.read_csv("1080Prices.csv") 
BCDATA = pd.read_csv("BitcoinPrice.csv")

gpu_dates = pd.to_datetime(GPUDATA["Date"])
gpu_prices = GPUDATA["Price_USD"]

btc_dates = pd.to_datetime(BCDATA["Date"])
btc_prices = BCDATA["Close"]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # Create a new Axes object sharing ax1's x-axis

ax1.plot(gpu_dates, gpu_prices, color='blue')
ax2.plot(btc_dates, btc_prices, color='red')
```

As you have not provided sample data, I am unable to show a relevant demonstration, but this should work.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for explaining it too. That will help me out tremendously later on in this project. Do you happen to know how to stretch the figure size a bit as well? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JackNovozinsky you're welcome! If you mean to increase the size of the figure, you would need to pass a `tuple` representing the size of the figure, in inches, to the `figsize` argument of `plt.subplots`. The documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) will explain more!

Comment: @JackNovozinsky I should also add that you can use the `sharex` parameter of `plt.subplots` for your current problem, but that might be a little less intuitive.